# Changing the NavigationBar chevron and title color has no effect

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to set the color of the navigation bar's back button and chevron of the back button.

My app starts with a navigation controller.

This navigation controller has a custom class withe these lines:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
  [super awakeFromNib];

  UIColor *white = [UIColor whiteColor];
  [self setTintColor: white];
//  [self setBarTintColor: white];

  UIFont *fonte = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Book" size:14.0f];
  NSDictionary *atributos =  @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : white,
                               NSFontAttributeName : fonte
                               };

  [self setTitleTextAttributes:atributos];

}
```

The root view controller of that navigation controller has the navigation bar hidden. This root view controller is called main screen.

From that view controller I push another one that has the navigation bar visible. That navigation bar has no back button added by me but iOS puts a back button and a chevron there "< main screen". That button and the chevron are both back.

Aren't these supposed to respect the settings on the navigation bar class that make those items white?

What is wrong?

Comment: Try [self.appearance setTintColor:[UIColor yourcolor]];

Comment: there is no self.appearance api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To globally set that color you could use something like this in you AppDelegate:

```
UINavigationBar *navBarAppearance = [UINavigationBar appearance];
[navBarAppearance setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Or in Swift:

```
let navBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

Comment: I tried that. The chevron changes color but not the back button text's color.

Comment: Odd, I use this all the time. In your original question is the last word in this sentence supposed to be "black"? "That button and the chevron are both back." If so - looks like you are overriding your global and local settings someplace else.

Comment: no. The class makes the items white, that is what I want but they are black.

Comment: I had an issue once where I had accidentally set the view's alpha to 0 and forgotten about it since it looked fine on an iPad. Did you check that?

Comment: found the problem. A second set of instructions like this forgotten on another part of the code. THANKS!